# GoogleMock: How to validate input parameters w.r.t number of invocations?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am writing unit tests for a C++ class using [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest) and [GoogleMock](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock). My current code looks like below:

```
MockNetConnector* connector = new MockNetConnector();
NetClient* client = new NetClient(connector);

TEST_F(NetClientTest, connect)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*connector, attempt_connect(_,_)).Times(3)
        .WillOnce(Return(false))
        .WillOnce(Return(false))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));

    std::string srv_list = "127.0.0.1:30001,127.0.0.2:30002,127.0.0.3:30003";
    bool is_connected = client->connect(srv_list);

    ASSERT_TRUE(is_connected);
}
```

As you can see, the `(*connector).attempt_connect(_,_)` currently does not validate input parameters. Now I want it to validate the input upon each invocation, i.e. input should be (127.0.0.**x**, 3000**x**) for the invocation *x-th*.

I know how to validate parameters for fixed values, e.g. `attempt_connect(StrEq("127.0.0.1"),Eq(30001))`, but don't know how to validate parameters that vary from invocation to invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the question, but maybe not the best.

First, define a global variable called `postfix`:

```
static int postfix = 0;
```

Write custom [matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#writing-new-matchers-quickly):

```
MATCHER(ValidateIP, "")
{
    std::string expected_ip = "127.0.0." + to_string(::ip_postfix);

    return (expected_ip == arg);
}

MATCHER(ValidatePort, "")
{
    int expected_port = 30000 + ::port_postfix;

    return (expected_port == arg);
}
```

Write a custom [action](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#writing-new-actions-quickly) that increases `postfix` after each invocation.

```
ACTION(IncreasePostfix)
{
    ::postfix++;
}
```

Apply the matchers to the expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*connector, attempt_connect(ValidateIP(),ValidatePort())).Times(3)
    .WillOnce(DoAll(IncreasePostfix(), Return(false)))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(IncreasePostfix(), Return(false)))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(IncreasePostfix(), Return(true)));
```

To make the `postfix` has effect individually to each test, reset them right before the test begins (i.e. inside `NetClientTest::SetUp()`)

```
class NetClientTest : public testing::Test
{
    virtual void SetUp() {
        ::postfix = 1;
    }

    // other methods
};
```